# Bringing $T$ inside the summation $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (\Delta_j W)^2$

Tags: summation, stochastic-processes

Let $\Delta_j W=W(t_{j+1})-W(t_j)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,t_{j+1}-t_j)=\mathcal{N}(0,T/n)$ for $j=0,1,\dots,n-1$. Here $t_j=jT/n$.

In a textbook that I was given for a class, the author has written that $$\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (\Delta_j W)^2-T\right)^2=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left(\left(\Delta_j W\right)^2-\frac{T}{n}\right)\right)^2.$$
I do not understand how the term $T$ was brought inside the summation. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{T}{n}.$$

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks very much!